# ComboBox SelectedItem vs SelectedValue

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

The following code works as you’d expect — `MyProperty` on the model is updated when the user picks a new item in the dropdown.

```
comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", myModel, "MyProperty", true,
DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

The following, however, doesn’t work the same way and the model update isn’t triggered until the input focus moves to another control on the form:

```
comboBox1.DataBindings.Add("SelectedItem", myModel, "MyProperty", true, 
DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Does anybody know why? I don’t even know where to start investigating the cause. Pointers in the right direction to start the investigation or an outright explanation would be equally appreciated.

*Aside*: for my purposes, I ended up binding to both `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`. This way I get instant model updates based on UI changes (through the `SelectedValue` binding), and UI updates based on programmatic model changes (through the `SelectedItem` binding).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx) control inherits from the [`ListControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.aspx) control.

The [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) property is a proper member of the `ComboBox` control. The event that is fired on change is [`ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectionchangecommitted.aspx)

**ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted**

> Occurs when the selected item has changed and that change is displayed in the ComboBox.

The [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) property is inherited from the `ListControl` control.
As such, this property will fire the [`ListControl.SelectedValueChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvaluechanged.aspx) event.

**ListControl.SelectedValueChanged**

> Occurs when the SelectedValue property changes.

That said, they won't fire the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).[`PropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event the same, but they will anyway. The only difference is in the firing event. `SelectedValueChanged` is fired as soon as a new selection is made from the list part of the ComboBox, and `SelectedItemChanged` is fired when the item is displayed in the TextBox portion of the ComboBox.

In short, they both represent something in the list part of the ComboBox. So, when binding either property, the result is the same, since the `PropertyChanged` event is fired in either case. And since they both represent an element from the list, the they are probably treated the same.

Does this help?

**EDIT #1**

Assuming that the list part of the ComboBox represents a property (as I can't confirm since I didn't write the control), binding either of `SelectedItem` or `SelectedValue` affects the same collection inside the control. Then, when this property is changed, the same occurs in the end. The `INotifyPropertryPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event is fired on the same property.

Comment: Order of events when all subscribed:
1  SelectionChangeCommitted,  
2  SelectedValueChanged,  
3  SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: I found this on MSDN: The SelectionChangeCommitted event is raised only when the user changes the combo box selection, and you can create a handler for this event to provide special handling for the ComboBox when the user changes the selected item in the list. However, depending on how the ComboBox is configured, and how the user changes the selected item, the SelectionChangeCommitted event may not be raised. Alternatively, you can handle the SelectedIndexChanged, but note that this event occurs whether the index is changed programmatically or by the user.

Answer (score 9):

I suspect that the SelectedItem property of the ComboBox does not change until the control has been validated (which occurs when the control loses focus), whereas the SelectedValue property changes whenever the user selects an item.

Here is a reference to the focus events that occur on controls:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validated.aspx

Comment: A better answer than mine.  It is also important to point out that you will not be able to use SelectedItem when bound to SelectedValue because it will not be updated yet.  If I remember correctly, you have to use retrieve from the Items collection of the list control by SelectedIndex.

Answer (score 2):

This is a long-standing "feature" of the list controls in .NET in my experience.  Personally, I would just bind to the on change of the SelectedValue property and write whatever additional code is necessary to workaround this "feature" (such as having two properties, binding to one for SelectedValue, and then, on the set of that property, updating the value from SelectedItem in your custom code).

Anyway, I hope that helps =D

Comment: I ended up setting up two bindings -- one to SelectedValue and one to SelectedItem and didn't need any custom code beyond that. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want Selected.Value being worked
you have to do following things:

```
1. Set DisplayMember
2. Set ValueMember
3. Set DataSource (not use Items.Add, Items.AddRange, DataBinding etc.)
```

The key point is Set DataSource!

Comment: Mine is working with SelectedValue while only setting DataSource and DisplayMember, not setting ValueMember. I was surprised.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to bind to a dictionary ie

```
  <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding Pathology, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                              ItemsSource="{x:Static RnxGlobal:CLocalizedEnums.PathologiesValues}" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key"
                              Margin="{StaticResource SmallMarginLeftBottom}"/>
```

then SelectedItem will not work whilist SelectedValue will

Comment: This is for WPF, not winforms