# ComboBox SelectedValue or SelectedItem Binding WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox that is binding to an `ObservableCollection` of strings in an object. This binding works, but I also want to bind whatever the user selects from this combobox, in a different property which is a string, in the same Object.  I cannot figure out whether I should use `SelectedValue` or `SelectedItem`, or if there is a problem beyond that.  Thank you in advance.

Here is what I have so far, I have omitted any code irrelevant to the problem:

**In XAML:**

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <my:JobItem x:Key="jobItemViewSource" />
</Grid.Resources>

<ComboBox x:Name="businessUnitBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BusinessUnits}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
        <Binding Path="BusinessUnit" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="Explicit" />
    </ComboBox.SelectedValue>
</ComboBox>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public string BusinessUnit
{
    get{  return businessUnit; }
    set
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(BusinessUnit) || !BusinessUnit.Equals(value))
        {
            businessUnit = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BusinessUnit");
        }
    }

}

public ObservableCollection<string> BusinessUnits
{
    get { return businessUnits; }
    set
    {
        if(!BusinessUnits.Equals(value))
        {
            businessUnits = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BusinessUnits");
        }

        businessUnits = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This may answer your question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883481/combobox-selecteditem-vs-selectedvalue

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want to use [`SelectedItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem). That'll give the actual item that was bound to it. [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue) is determined by the [`SelectedValuePath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath) property... which is just unnecessary in this case.
Also, you probably don't want to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to be `Explicit`. The default should be fine in that regard.