# How add items(Text & Value) to ComboBox & read them in SelectedIndexChanged (SelectedValue = null)

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I want to add some items to a combobox like this :

```
public class ComboboxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}

ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
item.Text = "choose a server...";
item.Value = "-1";
ComboBox_Servers.Items.Add(item);
...
```

and read those texts and values in `SelectedIndexChanged` like this :

```
private void ComboBox_Servers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ComboBox_Servers.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

But SelectedValue is always null! what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take the `SelectedItem` and cast it back to your `class` and access its `properties`.

```
 MessageBox.Show(((ComboboxItem)ComboBox_Countries_In_Silvers.SelectedItem).Value);
```

**Edit** You can try using DataTextField and DataValueField, I used it with DataSource.

```
ComboBox_Servers.DataTextField = "Text";
ComboBox_Servers.DataValueField = "Value";
```

Comment: You can try setting DataTextField and DataValueField properties with class properties and access value attribute then.

Comment: Updated my answer, tell me what it brings?

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
ComboBox cbx = new ComboBox();
cbx.DisplayMember = "Text";
cbx.ValueMember = "Value";
```

**EDIT** (a little explanation, sory, I also didn't notice your combobox wasn't bound, I blame the lack of caffeine):

The difference between SelectedValue and SelectedItem are explained pretty well here: [ComboBox SelectedItem vs SelectedValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883481/combobox-selecteditem-vs-selectedvalue)

So, if your combobox is not bound to datasource, DisplayMember and ValueMember doesn't do anything, and SelectedValue will always be null, SelectedValueChanged won't be called. So either bind your combobox:

```
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";

            List<ComboboxItem> list = new List<ComboboxItem>();

            ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
            item.Text = "choose a server...";
            item.Value = "-1";
            list.Add(item);

            item = new ComboboxItem();
            item.Text = "S1";
            item.Value = "1";
            list.Add(item);

            item = new ComboboxItem();
            item.Text = "S2";
            item.Value = "2";
            list.Add(item);

            cbx.DataSource = list; // bind combobox to a datasource
```

or use SelectedItem property:

```
if (cbx.SelectedItem != null)
             Console.WriteLine("ITEM: "+comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: It is not true that DisplayMember doesn't do anything. When using a non-databound combobox, the DisplayMember property DOES work. That is very confusing, cause one would expect SelectedValue to work also.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dictionary<int,string> comboSource = new Dictionary<int,string>();
comboSource.Add(1, "Sunday");
comboSource.Add(2, "Monday");
```

Aftr adding values to `Dictionary`, use this as `combobox` datasource:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = new BindingSource(comboSource, null);
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to some of the other answers, but is compact and avoids the conversion to dictionary if you already have a list.

Given a `ComboBox` "combobox" on a windows form and a class `SomeClass` with the `string` type property `Name`,

```
List<SomeClass> list = new List<SomeClass>();

combobox.DisplayMember = "Name";
combobox.DataSource = list;
```

Which means that `combobox.SelectedItem` is a `SomeClass` object from `list`, and each item in `combobox` will be displayed using its property `Name`.

You can read the selected item using

```
SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass)combobox.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        combo1.DisplayMember = "Text";
        combo1.ValueMember = "Value";   
        combo1.Items.Add(new { Text = "someText"), Value = "someValue") });
        dynamic item = combo1.Items[combo1.SelectedIndex];
        var itemValue = item.Value;
        var itemText = item.Text;
```

Unfortunatly "combo1.SelectedValue" does not work, i did not want to bind my combobox with any source, so i came up with this solution. Maybe it will help someone.