# Combobox.Text Vs combobox.Selecteditem Vs combobox.selectValue?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

What is the difference between each of these? 
Can I use any of these methods to display the text of a combo box in label, or is there any difference?

```
label1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
label2.Text = comboBox1.Text;
label3.Text = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

I am testing these values of the Combo box, but I'm confused as to how they work.
I want to display the text of a combo box in label. Using comboBox.Text it works fine but the remaining two give the following error:

```
error message:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: In what way do you want your code to work?

Comment: Did you read their documentations first? And what is not working exactly? Any error message or exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my example.

```
private void comboSelectChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
  textBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
  textBox2.Text = comboBox1.Text;
  textBox3.Text = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
}
```

Items collection:
[image]

And the results:

[image: One selected]

[image: Two selected]

[image: Three selected]

---

**SelectedItem:** Gets or sets currently selected item in the ComboBox.
     *Based on ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted*

**Text:** Gets or sets the text associated with this control. (Overrides Control.Text.)
*setting the text value will change the current value of the combobox*

**SelectedValue:** Gets or sets the value of the member property specified by the ValueMember property. (Inherited from ListControl.)
     *Based on ListControl.SelectedValueChanged*

This question might be a duplicate of [ComboBox SelectedItem vs SelectedValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883481/combobox-selecteditem-vs-selectedvalue).

Source [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
Further reading at [dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/combobox).

Comment: Thanks but give me any technical answer i am confuse