# Displaying Text from Combobox Selections C#

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am trying to create a simple Windows Form App in VS 2013 using C#.  The form has 2 combo boxes with some strings to select from.  I am trying to display results in 2 text boxes based upon those selections, but when I run the program the results do not display.  I placed the code in the method for selecting values from the combo boxes.   Here is what I have:

```
private void SiteList_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string SiteSelect = SiteList.SelectedValue.ToString();
    string DateSelect = dateList.SelectedValue.ToString();


   if (SiteSelect == "Alaska"  &&  DateSelect = "January 2014")
   {
       actualResults.Text = "$391,015.92";
       estimateResults.Text = "No Estimate Available";
   } 
}
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on your `if` line and debug, what are the values of SiteSelect and DateSelect?

Comment: Show how items was added to the `ComboBox`

Answer (score 0):

try this instead :

```
string SiteSelect = SiteList.SelectedItem.ToString();
string DateSelect = dateList.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

SelectedItem is the way to select the object in the comboBox. Value will select only the display string (I don't know why but it doesn't work all the time). I always use SelectedItem with toString() to get the object as string

Comment: Ok. And what is the difference to the code of the OP?

Comment: SelectedItem is the way to select the object in the comboBox. Value will select only the display string (I don't know why but it doesn't work all the time). I always use SelectedItem with toString() to get the object as string

Comment: You should have written that short info along with your answer. Pls. remember this for the next time.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Use this `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`

like this

```
string Site = SiteList.SelectedItem.ToString();
string Date = dateList.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are subscribed to the `SelectedValueChanged` event.
This event will be fired only when items was added by setting `DataSource` property

```
Me.ComboBox.DataSource = yourListOfItems;
```

If items was added manually (as I assume)

```
Me.ComboBox.Items.Add(yourNextItem);
```

Then you need to subscribe to the `SelectionChangesCommitted` event
And as other answers said use `SelectedItem` for getting selected value

Because `SelectedValue`, in the case when items added manually, will return `null`

Check this: [ComboBox SelectedItem vs SelectedValue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2883923/1565525)