# How do I show the selected value of a combobox in a label c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get the selected value of the Combo box and display that in a label. It is in a c# winForm. This is what i have now:

```
private void AccountsCmboBx_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            string accountName = AccountsCmboBx.SelectedValue.ToString();
            FromAddrLabel.Text = accountName;
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
        }

}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: And what's the issue? Is there an exception being thrown?

Comment: I get an exception saying: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: SelectedValue only works if you have the ValueMember property set when using a DataSouce.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
   string accountName = AccountsCmboBx.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

Please see the difference in post [ComboBox SelectedItem vs SelectedValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883481/combobox-selecteditem-vs-selectedvalue)

Comment: @James Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

```
string accountName = AccountsCmboBx.Text;
```

Will never have a NullReferenceException if there is no item selected.

Answer (score 0):

if the text is the value you want, try:

```
string accountName =  AccountsCmboBx.SelectedText;
```